# How to use presentModalViewController in Android?

Tags: android, animated, model-view

Currently i am working in Android application, In iphone application Using presentModalViewController to animate view from bottom to top on a screen, similarly in Android application, How to use presentModalViewController Control in Android? Is it possible to add this? I refer the internet but i got only MVC pattern, so please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Using presentModalViewController in iPhone apps:

```
 bookview *book = [[bookview alloc]init];  
    UINavigationController *navi = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:book];
    [self presentModalViewController:navi animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no NavigationController in android, instead android activities are pushed and pop from the activity stack, maintained by ActivityManager.

To Add animation on start or stop of an activity, please read animations, or go through following answer, to learn:

[Start Activity with an animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625812/start-activity-with-an-animation)