# Start Activity with Sliding Menu slide animation

Tags: java, android, android-activity, menu, sliding

I implemented the Sliding Menu library in my app but I have an issue with the navigation.
In the behind view, I've set some buttons which when pressed change the Fragment of my current Activity. Normally, when the fragment is changed, the Activity slides back in it's place. 
But I encountered a problem and I am forced to use a new Activity on button click. The thing is that, when I start the new Activity, it opens a new "screen" (as expected). What I want to do is to slide the screen back to it's original position with the new Activity in. Any way I could do that?
Basically, I want to launch an Activity with Drop-Down navigation and 2 normal activities.

Comment: Let's not try and navigate around the problem and fix this at the core. Please explain: "Normally, when the fragment is changed, the Activity slides back in it's place. But I encountered a problem and I am forced to use a new Activity on button click."

Comment: You can try to hide menu programmatically and start your new Activity with an animation (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625812/start-activity-with-an-animation).

Comment: @Rawkode Well, basically my app at the moment consists of 3 activities. 2 normal activities and 1 activity with Drop-Down Navigation. I want to link these 3 activities with the buttons on the sliding menu.
I am forced to use 3 activities because the Drop-Down menu would remain in all fragments if I used a single activity.