# Activity launched by launcher, Custom Animation

Tags: android, animation

I have an app, which uses a custom ActionBar.Whenever my app is launched by the launcher (or any other app), it has a zoom in animation, of an empty view with Default ActionBar, when the animation finishes, I get my view, and this transition doesn't look that good.

I've found the following [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XNF8pXr6whU), which shows how to create an animation within your app.**Can I change the lunch animation to a custom Bitmap, and how?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5018385/198996

You'll have to create your own theme with a custom android:windowAnimationStyle.

Some additional resources on animations in XML:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html
- http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-animations-quick-guide.html
- http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/07/7-simple-useful-android-xml-animations/

Comment: This answer is great, but it lakes of explanation about the animation xml file itself.

Comment: I'm sure there's lots of documentation about animations in Android out there.

Comment: @KirillKulakov would you mind marking my answer as correct if it helped you?